# Why is "this.Repo“ null when invoking methods in SongRepo in Spring Boot Project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The goal of this method is to provide functionality to a service layer method that will find all songs within a PostgreSQL database. I have implemented an interface "SongServiceInterface" in the service layer and in the event I utilize this SongService via instantiation in the main method or even by sending Http Requests via "/songs" endpoint, I receive this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.techm.react.Wasteland.repository.SongRepo.findAll()" because "this.songRepo" is null.

Please note upon startup the application will persist the objects to database, but using endpoints or methods within this repo/service cause null field error.

I can provide the code below:

---

### Model

```
package com.techm.react.Wasteland.models;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Time;

@Entity
@Table(name = "song")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JoinColumn(name = "album")
    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Album album;

    @Column(name = "artists")
    private String artists;

    @Column(name = "track")
    private int track;

    @Column(name = "track_length")
    private Time length;
}
```

---

### DTO

```
package com.techm.react.Wasteland.dto;

import com.techm.react.Wasteland.models.Album;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Time;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SongDTO {

    private String title;
    private AlbumDTO album;
    private String artists;
    private int track;
    private Time length;


}
```

---

### Repo

```
package com.techm.react.Wasteland.repository;

import com.techm.react.Wasteland.models.Song;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public interface SongRepo extends JpaRepository<Song, Integer> {

    public abstract List<Song> findAll();

    public abstract List<Song> findByArtist();

    public abstract Song findByTrack();
}
```

---

### Service

```
package com.techm.react.Wasteland.service;

import com.techm.react.Wasteland.dto.SongDTO;
import com.techm.react.Wasteland.models.Song;
import com.techm.react.Wasteland.repository.SongRepo;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service @Configurable
public class SongService implements SongServiceInterface{
    @Autowired
    SongRepo songRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public List<SongDTO> findAllSongs() {

        List<SongDTO> songDTOS = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Song> songs = songRepo.findAll();
        for(Song s: songs) {
            songDTOS.add(modelMapper.map(s, SongDTO.class));
        }

        return songDTOS;
    }

    public SongDTO getSongByTitle(String title) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        SongDTO song = new SongDTO();
        if(title == song.getTitle()){
            return song;
        }
        else throw new NoSuchFieldException("The song by that title does not exist");
    }

    public SongDTO findByTrack(int track) {
        SongDTO song = new SongDTO();
        if(song.getTrack() == track) {
            return song;
        }
        return null;
    }



}
```

---

### Main

```
package com.techm.react.Wasteland;

import com.techm.react.Wasteland.controller.AlbumController;
import com.techm.react.Wasteland.controller.SongController;
import com.techm.react.Wasteland.service.SongService;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.server", "com.server.config"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class WastelandApplication {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        return modelMapper;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WastelandApplication.class, args);

        SongService songService = new SongService();
        System.out.println(songService.findAllSongs());
    }

}
```

Comment: @EraftYps even in doing this, I receive the same error when I try to invoke said methods

Comment: Because you are newing up SongService and circumventing Spring.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new` to create an object, it's outside of Spring's context.  It won't have the autowired dependencies.  Also, you won't be able to use autowired beans in your main (nor should you) as it's a static method.  If you want to do this in your app startup, autowire the bean and put the logic in a PostConstruct method.

Here is an example:

```
public class WastelandApplication {
    @Autowired
    private SongService songService;

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        return modelMapper;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WastelandApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomethingIProbablyShouldNotBeDoing() {
        System.out.println(songService.findAllSongs());
    }
}
```